# A Lebesgue measurable function $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is always uniformly continuous on some set $B\subset [0,1]$ and $\mu(B)>0$. True or false?

Tags: real-analysis

A Lebesgue measurable function $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is always uniformly continuous on some set $B\subset [0,1]$ and $\mu(B)>0$. True or false?

A function $ f(x) $ is uniformly continuous on $ B$ if for $ a, a+h\in B $,   $|f (a+h)-f (a)| < \epsilon$ whenever $|h| < \delta$ . Where $\delta >0,\epsilon>0$

Comment: It looks like B may be very weird.  Example: f(x)=0 on rational numbers and f(x)=1 on irrationals.  Then f(x) is uniformly continuous on B=irrationals with measure=1.

Comment: @herbsteinberg yeah and that makes me think the result is likey true

Comment: Careful with the wording: herb's function is not continuous on $B$; rather, $f|_B$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very true! By Lusin's Theorem there exits a continuous function $g$ on $[0,1]$ such that $\mu \{x:f(x) \neq g(x)\} <1/2$. Let $B=\{x:f(x)=g(x)\}$. Then $\mu (B)>1/2$ and $f$ coincide with $g$ on $B$ so $f$ is uniformly continuous on $B$. $g$ is uniformly continuous on $B$ because it is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$.

Comment: But the set $ B $ is not necessarily compact, so you cant conclude that $ g (x) $ is uniformly continuous on $ B$

Comment: @Abdullahi_A_Ibrahim  $g$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$ and hence it is uniformly continuous on any subset of $[0,1]$.